# How to get min and max time for multiple fields using influx query?

Tags: node.js, influxdb, influxdb-2, influx-javascript

I want to get min and max time for given multiple fields.

I'm able to get min *or* max time using following influx query. I'm not sure if it is true or not but seems like working to me.

```
const fluxQuery =  `from(bucket: "xxx")
        |> range(start: 0)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] =~ /^sensor1|sensor2$/)        // targeting multiple fields
        |> group(columns: ["_field"])                                   // don't know what is the use
        |> keep(columns: ["_time","_field", "_value"])                  // in result, I want to get time, field and value columns
        |> min(column: "_time") `                                       // to get min value on time AND use max to get max time
```

1. Is the above query right?
2. As you can see above, I have to use either max or min individually. Is there a combined way to get min and max time together in a single query?

I have the following code written in Node.js to get data from influxDB 2.0:

```
const myQuery = async () => {
  for await (const { values, tableMeta } of queryApi.iterateRows(fluxQuery)) {
    const o = tableMeta.toObject(values);
    console.log("field", o['_field'])
    console.log("time", o['_time'])
    console.log("value", o['_value'])
  }
}


myQuery()
```

and it prints the following output:

```
field sensor1
time 2024-01-02T21:54:26.7Z
value 212259004416

field sensor2
time 2024-01-02T22:36:51.837Z
value 1000
```